# QuickBlox Video Upload Issue

Tags: ios, iphone, quickblox

I'm working on a CHAT APP with quickblox API.
I am facing issue with Video file UPLOAD.
I am able to upload IMAGE file easily.

For image i use this  code from Quickblox API.

[Click Here](http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-content-ios#Upload_file)

What i just change is :

```
NSData *imageData11=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:delegate.videoURLDelegate];
[QBContent TUploadFile:imageData11 fileName:@"ChatVideo" contentType:@"video/mp4" isPublic:YES delegate:self];
```

Thank You in advance

Comment: I debug this and found that in this object "imageData11" no video details coming..It says <null>

Comment: Yes, because it's  videoURLDelegate - not sure what is that, but i think there is no file with this location, please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> hello, i have the same issue i found it buy calling this
>
> "https://s3.amazonaws.com/qbprod/" to upload video its working for me.
>
> hope help you also